# Why do we multiply by 10^-9 here?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

**Question**

---

What is the instantaneous amplitude of a sinusoidal signal with period T = 5hS and peak Amplitude of 10 @ t = 2.5 h s

f(t)    =   A.sin (w.t)

f(t)    =   A.sin (2.p.f.t)

f(t)    =   A.sin (2.p . (1/T) . t)

f(t)    =   10.sin (2.p . (1/5 x 10-9) . 2.5 x 10-9)

f(t)    =   10.sin (2.p . 200 x 10+6 . 2.5 x 10-9)

f(t)    =   0

I follow the formula through to the point where you multiply by 10^9, why is that done here?

f(t)    =   10.sin (2.p . (1/5 . **10-9**) . 2.5 . **10-9**)

Comment: Are you sure the question say hs and not ns?

Comment: I copied this from the webpage that was sent to us. If you're sure that it is a mistake I should email my professor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I will assume that both S and s in the question are used for seconds and that superscripts in the copied soloution were lost due to copy and paste).

> I follow the formula through to the point where you multiply by 10^9, why is that done here?

f(t) = A.sin (2.p . (1/T) . t)

This formula requires that "T" and "t" are in consistent units.

multiplying by $10^{-9}$ is essentially changing the units from hectoseconds to hectogigaseconds. This doesn't change the answer because your units are still consistent but changing your units from a weird unit (hectoseconds) to a really-weird unit (hectogigaseconds) is not something you would normally do.

So why did the writer of that answer do it?

Many people preffer to use SI units everywhere. In simple problems like this it doesn't matter but in more complex problems it's easier to use SI units everywhere than to work out whether your choice of non-SI units is consistent.

My guess is that the problem originally said "ns" (nanoseconds, a fairly common unit) rather than "hs" (hectoseconds, a weird unit). Somewhere along the line the units in the question got changed, maybe a typo, maybe deliberately throwing in a weird unit to keep students on thier toes but the worked answer got left alone leaving it "correct but weird".